# refreshing a div on a button click

Tags: javascript, html, reload

how can i refresh div tag? i have this code:

```
<div id="xvote-{$link_shakebox_index}" class="votebutton">
                        {if $anonymous_vote eq "false" and $user_logged_in eq ""}
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#loginModal" class="btn {if $link_shakebox_currentuser_votes eq 1}btn-success{else}btn-default{/if}"><i class="fa {if $link_shakebox_currentuser_votes eq 1}fa-white {/if}fa-sun-o"></i></a>
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#loginModal" class="btn {if $link_shakebox_currentuser_reports eq 1}btn-danger{else}btn-default{/if}"><i class="fa {if $link_shakebox_currentuser_reports eq 1}fa-white {/if}fa-moon-o"></i></a>
                        {/if}
</div>
```

Comment: On which event do you want to refresh it?

Comment: You are clearly using a server-side language here. Which one?

Comment: Refresh something in the client that was generated by the server is more tricky than you might think. What language are you using ? Because this gives a parsing error in HTML.

Comment: i want when user click on btn all of <div> tag reload again without page reloading.

Comment: i use this code to user can vote on links

Comment: `{if $anonymous_vote eq "false" and $user_logged_in eq ""}` this is not HTML, please tell us what code it is. Because it doesn't modifies the div tag in the client, but in the server.

Comment: i don't know Too! can you tell me how can i refresh div with java or jQ?

Comment: OK let me state it one more time, your example is not "compilable". You do not provide enough information for us to understand how to solve your problem. 
In this case, there is code snippet that is not HTML, and I don't recognize it.
If you don't know, then how shall we ?
What does refreshing mean to you ? Reload the HTML code ? Does it imply some changes in the div ?

Comment: my english is not good so i writ my problem step by step:1-i have a site like digg. 2-in my site user can vote on links.vote can be "+" or "-". 3-when users click on "+" or "-" they can un-vote by re-click. 4-if we reloading page users can not un-vote. 5-i want users can not un-vote.

Answer (score 1):

You put

```
 {if $anonymous_vote eq "false" and $user_logged_in eq ""}
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#loginModal" class="btn {if $link_shakebox_currentuser_votes eq 1}btn-success{else}btn-default{/if}"><i class="fa {if $link_shakebox_currentuser_votes eq 1}fa-white {/if}fa-sun-o"></i></a>
                            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#loginModal" class="btn {if $link_shakebox_currentuser_reports eq 1}btn-danger{else}btn-default{/if}"><i class="fa {if $link_shakebox_currentuser_reports eq 1}fa-white {/if}fa-moon-o"></i></a>
                        {/if}
```

Which does not make sense at all, because:

1. The if statement is not a html code.
2. You are not using a server-side.
3. You can not refresh a div using a client side only.

In Order to refresh a div, you should use a server-side language like (Java, PHP and etc..).

For the Java code, you will have to create 2 files:

1. A JSP (Java Server Page) which will contain your HTML code.
2. A Java File Which will be the server-side processing.

-For the JSP File, you will need to make a link/button for the user to click in order to refresh a certain div.

-For the Java File, you will need to import some libraries Like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
```

And then create the class for Example "Refresh" and implement the doGet method. At the end you will have to redirect the user to the same page.

```
public class Refresh extends HttpServlet {

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  throws IOException, ServletException {

  HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
              session.setAttribute("Example", Div.Refresh());
//The Div.Refresh() is another class with method Refresh, so you will have to create what will the refresh do in another Java Filed called"Div."
                response.sendRedirect("THE_SAME_PAGE.jsp");

               }
}
```

I Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much Abdelrahman, i read your answer, i have these file in my root, but i do not know how to use correctly, but i try to learn it. thanks again.